# ArcGIS Server Object Extenstion REST Endpoint That Supports GET and POST

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, server-object-extension

I have a Server Object Extension for ArcGIS Server 10.0, that implements IRESTRequestHandler.  The extension contains many individual RestOperations.  By default each RestOperation supports HTTP GETs when using the extension.  In the RestOperation constructor, there is a parameter called postOnly, which is a boolean.  If I set postOnly = true, then the endpoint will only support HTTP POSTs, and will throw an exception if you attempt to use a GET.  I would like to create an endpoint that supports both GET and POST.  If you interrogate some of the supported methods on a standard MapService like Find and Identify, you will notice these support both GET and POST:

- http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/identify
- http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/find

Does anyone know of a way to implement this on a custom Server Object Extension?

Comment: Have you tried creating your mapservice with feature access enabled? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//009300000022000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested a GET and POST request with my custom SOE, and it accepts both GET and POST requests just fine without any special configuration.  `postOnly=true` as you know will force POST only requests, and should be used when data is modified.  What kind of a response do you get when you try and submit a POST request to your SOE?

Comment: How obvious!  I was hung up on why the REST endpoint page did not have a separate button for GET and POST.  I just tested it on my SOE and it works fine with GET and POST.  Thanks!